# Redux and Flow, how to combine various action types when using 'ducks' approach

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I'm using the very useful Todos-Flow redux example provided by the redux team, but I'm a bit stumped at one point. The example defines an 'Action' type with the following approach (i.e all in one place):

```
export type Action =
  { type: 'ADD_TODO', id: Id, text: Text }
| { type: 'TOGGLE_TODO', id: Id }
| { type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER', filter: VisibilityFilter }
;

export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Action>;

export type Dispatch = ReduxDispatch<Action>;
```

However I'm trying to use the 'ducks' approach where my actions, action creators and reducers are all coupled to individual functionalities. So for example I'm trying to have more individualised actions defined in each 'ducks' file like so:

```
export type NavigationAction =
 { type: 'MENU_TOGGLE', toggleState: ToggleState }
| { type: 'CLOSE_MENU' }
| { type: 'UPDATE_SCROLL_LOCATION', scrollLocation: Destination }
;
```

The idea is that I would then have similar generic store, action, dispatch type definitions in my top level store file where I combine reducers etc (before coupling the store to my app), the difference being that now my action types are spread across their relevant functionalities.

I guess I'm just a bit scared to mess with the status quo per se as I understand the Redux and Flow relationship is quite complicated. Would it be a suitable approach to import each of my action type definitions, and then combine them all as the more general 'Action' type used in the example? If so how would I do this? Cheers!

Comment: Just define a union `type Action = NavigationAction | FooAction | BarAction | ...`?

Comment: Oh wow it really is that easy! Sorry these unions etc are all new to me and I didn't know where to begin. Thanks so much